# Java: Comparing two created cards from a deck

Tags: java, comparison

So I have a card class, deck class, and a game class. I have everything situated, except that I'm trying to compare a random card the computer generates, to a card that the player picks.

Here is my String array of cards:

```
String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                            "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
```

And here is my compareTo method, that I've implemented from Comparable to compare the generated card to the card the player has chosen, and return the higher of the two:

```
    public int compareTo(Card crd)
{
    Card card1;
    int card1Suit = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    int card1Rank = (int) (Math.random() * 13);
    card1 = new Card(a,b);
    if(card1.getRank().charAt(0) < crd.getRank().charAt(0))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I understand that just comparing the first character of the String array element isn't correct, but I don't know what to use to get the correct comparison to return the higher card. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `Card card1;` variable in this method. Not only is it not needed, it's dangerous and risks your throwing a NullPointerException. Instead use the fields in the current instance that this method is being called from, the `this`.

To determine rank, you need to iterate through the arrays using a for loop, and then decide where the current card's fields are in relation to the parameter Card's fields, and then return the appropriate number.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `enum` for both the ranks and suits. You could directly compare the enum values with each other for equality with the `equals` method. You could use the enumeration order of the enum literals to provide a natural ordering for the ranks, or explicitely specifying a *rank value* through a custom constructor for the enum values.